# upper bound on the size of a DFA for A|B given the DFAs for A and B?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, regular-expressions, dfa

Given RegEx `A` and `B` where the size of the compiled DFAs are `m` and `n` respectively, what is the upper bound on the size of the compile DFA for `A|B`? It shouldn't be hard to show that it can't be more than `n*m` but can a lower upper bound be shown?

What about other related case:

- What is the expected case for real world examples? Is it less than `n+m`?
- What about the three part case with `A`, `B` and `C`?

Answer (score 9):

The upper bound of $nm$ follows from the usual Cartesian product construction that you will find in just about any book on automata theory.  A lower bound of $nm$ is observed (for the case $\operatorname{gcd}(n,m) = 1$) in this paper:

> Sheng Yu.  State Complexity of Regular Languages.  Journal of Automata, Languages and Combinatorics, 2001.

The lower bound is proved for DFAs that I would consider to exist in the real world -- but if you want an expectation you will have to be more precise about the distribution from which $A$ and $B$ are drawn.

The bound is simple and can surely be extended to three DFAs.

Comment: For "real would" examples, I guess the constraint is RE that you find someone using rather than create. As with anything that steps outside theory it's ill defined and hard to play with.

Comment: The DFAs that Yu uses to prove the lower bound of $nm$ are natural, as opposed to being contrived for the sake of the proof: they simply decide whether the length of the input string is divisible by $n$ or $m$, respectively.  Although I have no formal justification for saying so, my intuition is that the number of states required to recognize $A\cup B$ is likely to be on the order of $nm$ (as opposed to $n+m$, say) unless there is some special relationship between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: My intuition is that most pairs of RE will quickly diverge to states where only A or only B is a possible match and will very often be non-diverging before that.